# Can logging module in Python log out data without the format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

When using the logging module I would sometimes like to print a simple line without the format string (Prints Date) being applied to the output.

I might want to log a separator line without the time stamp created by the set by the format string.  Or, my code might perform several actions between log events and cause another string to be logged.  Is this possible?  Example:

```
class Logger( ):
    def __init__( self, path ):
        msgFormat   = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d\t%(message)s'
        dateFormat  = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        logging.basicConfig( format=msgFormat, datefmt=dateFormat, filename=path, level=logging.INFO )

    def Log ( self, theStr ):
        logging.info( str( theStr ))


log = Logger( validPath )
log.SimpleLog( '-' * 4 )
log.Log( 'Some message' )
# Do some more stuff here
log.SimpleLog( '    Write some more stuff here' )
# Do some more stuff here
```

The output would look like:

```
----
11/13/2019 Some Message
    Write some more stuff here
```

I'm in Python 3.7 on Macintosh.  My logger class does not open the file directly and simply uses logging.BasicConfig() to get things rolling.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Your logging always adds a time stamp in front of the message?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, of course, there is a format string used in the logging class.  Adding a simple version of my logger class.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to do what you are asking. The idea is to set the formatter to just output the message in SimpleLog and restore it to the previous format after the log is done. This is a bit of a quick and dirty solution, if you want something more sustainable in a larger codebase the best way would be to use a custom formatter that inspects the `extra` and adds the time based on some key of it.

```
import logging

class Logger( ):
    msgFormat   = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d\t%(message)s'
    simpleFormat = '%(message)s'
    dateFormat  = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

    def __init__( self, path ):
        logging.basicConfig( format=self.msgFormat, datefmt=self.dateFormat, filename=path, level=logging.INFO )

    def Log ( self, theStr ):
        logging.info( str( theStr ))

    def SimpleLog( self, theStr ):
        for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:
            handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(self.simpleFormat, self.dateFormat))
        logging.info( str( theStr ))

        for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:
            handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(self.msgFormat, self.dateFormat))

validPath='logs.txt'

log = Logger( validPath )
log.SimpleLog( '-' * 4 )
log.Log( 'Some message' )
# Do some more stuff here
log.SimpleLog( '    Write some more stuff here' )
# Do some more stuff here
```

Comment: Youch... more complicated than expected.  I was hoping I missed a function or setting that would just do that.  I'll give it a shot and return my result in the next 1/2 hour.

Comment: Terrific... I optimized the code slightly and some of the callers.  My log is already much more readable and lighter.  TY!!  I'll hope that there is a more official way in the future since the logger module could easily provide another function that prints it out without having to change the formatter.  This is GREAT!! for now.